# Creating Derby in Memory DB SQLSyntaxException

Tags: java, oracle, maven, derby

I'm trying to create a Derby in Memory DB for testing, to mirror an Oracle db we use.  I've tried to execute the first script that we use set up the Oracle db, but I'm getting a SQLSyntaxException.

Maven:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
   <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
   <version>10.10.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Code:

```
private static String sqlStatement ="set echo on\n" + 
        "set feedback on\n" + 
        "set serveroutput on\n" + 
        "var start_date  varchar2(80);\n" + 
        "var start_date  varchar2(80);\n" + 
        "var end_date    varchar2(80);\n" + 
        "var sid         varchar2(10);\n" + 
        "var host        varchar2(30);\n" + 
        "var user        varchar2(30);\n" + 
        "spool DS_Create_Schema.log;\n" + 
        "\n" + 
        "begin\n" + 
        "  select to_char(sysdate, 'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') into :start_date from dual;\n"
        ...

final String sql = sqlStatement;
final String connURL = "jdbc:derby:memory:memdatabase;create=true";
Connection conn = null;
try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL);
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    boolean success = ps.execute();
    System.out.println("Memory database created: " + success);


} catch (SQLException e) {...
```

Comment: `set feedback on` and all the other commands are SQL*Plus commands - specific to Oracle's commandline tool. They won't work anywhere else (they are not even regular SQL statements - so you couldn't even run that Java program agains an Oracle database). Why do you think Derby understands the proprietary commands of Oracle's commandline client?

Answer (score 0):

Most of your Oracle SQL*PLus is not supported by Derby, you will have to convert it to more standard SQL.

Comment: The SQL*Plus commands can not even be run against an Oracle database through JDBC

Comment: @Greg-449, do you know of any other in memory databases that would support these scripts?

Comment: As far as I know this is all specific to the Oracle tool.